Python: Reading a CSV file with different encryptions but bypassing first few rows
I have a CSV file where the first 8 rows explain the file and the data starts on row 10. I tried skipping the data first, however, it gave me errors with reading the file:
I included the names=range(20) because it kept expecting a smaller range.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os # Check path
import csv
import glob

# Check path
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)
data = pd.read_csv('Events.csv', encoding="utf-8", names = range (20))

Output:
The output was 's' for row 1 col 1, and 'NaN' for the rest of the dataframe, as 'utf-8' is the encoding for the top portion and 'cp1252' is the encoding for the data itself.
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   s   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
When I open the csv file and delete the first few rows, I am able to read the file. I don't want to open the file and delete the first few rows to make this code work, as I want this code to work for similar csv's that I provide it (the file changes depending on what time it is as it stores events).
Is there a way to get past the first few rows and see my data?

Are you sure your file has two forms of encoding? Maybe the skiprows keyword argument to pd.read_csv() will help

pd.read_csv('Events.csv', encoding="utf-8", skiprows=8)

You would get an error not NaN if the encoding was off I'm pretty sure

I checked the encding: # Check encoding
with open('Events.csv') as f:
print(f). It did give me one encoding: 'cp1252', but I am still receiving 'NaN' values

@MichelleBogush Based on your comment in response to Andrês' answer, maybe you should close this

Try
data = pd.read_csv('Events.csv', encoding="utf-8", skiprows=10)


Skipping the rows doesn't help as I believe it is confused on how the data is viewed. It produces the following: Unnamed: 0 0 NaN 1 NaN 2 NaN 3 NaN 4 NaN

I think the issue is not the encoding but the data in the first few rows, which doesn't have the same amount of columns. I will start a new thread.
